# Use dynamic JSON page for Bubble Cloud d3.js

Tags: json, csv, d3.js

I am creating bubble cloud using these sample codes in Github. https://github.com/vlandham/bubble_cloud

The codes are using .csv in data folder. But I want to create a page showing dynamic data. Now I have the link to the dynamic JSON page.

How to implement the codes to make the bubble cloud dynamic with the JSON page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for somethign like the d3.json function? There are a bunch of request functions built into d3. Check [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)